How to fix the image picker failing on first try
I have an image picker in my application which works fine most of the time, expect in the first try on iOS.
The first time you click it, it shows the permission popup, then it gives me this error
[Backend] Failed to access application key window, unable to present library picker
[Backend] Failed to determine root view controller

And nothing happens, on second click it gives me an error that
PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)

And in live build it actually crashes.
After that it works fine.
The code is nothing special really, just simple
  final PickedFile? file = await _picker.pickImage(
                        source: ImageSource.gallery);

I couldn't find this error message anywhere. Has anyone has any idea what this can be?

Have you set the following keys in plist file?
Add the following keys to your Info.plist file, located in <project root>/ios/Runner/Info.plist:
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription - describe why your app needs permission for the photo library. This is called Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description in the visual editor.
This permission will not be requested if you always pass false for requestFullMetadata, but App Store policy requires including the plist entry.
NSCameraUsageDescription - describe why your app needs access to the camera. This is called Privacy - Camera Usage Description in the visual editor.
Add the keys like the following:
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>LetUserPickImage</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>LetUserCaptureImage</string>


thanks for the tip, I have those strings, they are not the main issue
